# Scala/Implicit/Playframework/Action: Wrapping Action Function

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming

It's exactly a Scala question, but it is in the context of the PlayFramework Action:

An Action takes something in the form **(play.api.mvc.Request => play.api.mvc.Result)**. And then you'll pass a block like:

```
{ request =>
  Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
}
```

Now I have defined a function with the same signature. One with and one without implicit for request.

```
  def WithUser2(request: Request[AnyContent])(block: (Request[AnyContent]) => Result):Result = {
    block(request)
  }
  def WithUser3(block: (Request[AnyContent]) => Result)(implicit request: Request[AnyContent]):Result = {
    block(request)
  }
```

I'm calling it this way now (2 versions):

```
  def index2 = Action { implicit request => WithUser2(request) { request =>
      Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready. " ))
  }}

  def index3 = Action ( implicit request => WithUser3 { request =>
      Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready. " ))
  })
```

Is there a way to directly attach my function to Action? I mean without placing **implicit request =>** before WithUserX so that my function replaces the complete block after Action directly? Now my function is inside the block and I think this is the problem why I need to pass request forward. So I need a way to get rid of the block around my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do, because `WithUserX` essentially does nothing special. It seems like you're trying to make your own `Action`, and for that we have [Action Composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition).

If you were to define a new `Action` like this:

```
object WithUser extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
        // Do something special maybe?
        block(request)
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
def index = WithUser { request =>
    ...
    Ok("Ok!")
}
```

This would be much better than trying to stuff it within the stock `Action`, when it doesn't need to be.

Comment: I already used ActionBuilder with WrappedRequest to create my own action. It worked, but I didn't manage to pass addional parameters to that my new UserAction. Further more I'm still new to Scala and it always is a fight to find all needed information. The information on the Play Framework site is often not enough, if you are not a Scala pro and understand the source code of the framework. So this place might not be the best, but its much more transparent to me what I'm doing.

Comment: The main reason for my post was to ask, if I can replace the action block with my function instead of calling my function from within the block. Or if there is a way to get rid of the first **request =>** to shorten the code. I mean my function has the same signature then the anonymous function in the block.

Comment: @bebo You'd still have to pass the request to your function, so no, you wouldn't be able to remove it. Which is why I suggest just making your function a custom `Action` instead, and replacing the controller function entirely with that.

Comment: Is there a way to pass an additional parameter to invokeBlock in ActionBuilder?